# RegEx JavaScript : Symbol extraction after digit

Tags: javascript, regex

My data :

```
abc3# de2! fghi1?
```

What I need is a RegEx that will extract the symbol that comes right after the digit (1, 2 or 3) so that the match will be : `#`, `!`, `?`

I've looked into non capturing groups and such but couldn't get it to work properly : `(?:1|2|3)[\S]+`

Comment: Do you want the character after **any** digit, or just after "1", "2", and "3"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is more or less correct, I'd use

```
\d([^\w\s]+)
```

and then you'd need to use `RegExp#exec`:

```js
var re = /\d([^\w\s]+)/g;                  // Declare the regex
var str = 'abc3# de2! fghi1?';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) { // find a match
    res.push(m[1]);                   // Get the captured value only
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

The regex matches

- `\d` - a digit
- `([^\w\s]+)` - a capture group matching 1+ non-word and non-whitespace symbols.

If you want to make sure to match only at the end of "words" or string, you can use `/\d([^\w\s]+)(?=\s|$)/g` regex.

Comment: Yep . . . this is pretty much what I would use.  Only thing that I might change is the regex pattern, depending on some clarifications to the capture rules.

Answer (score 0):

You need `\d(\W)` to capture a symbol after a number, see [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/jY9iR1/1)

Answer (score 0):

[Capturing symbol after `n` number of digits](https://regex101.com/r/xZ1vL1/1):

```
\d([\:#!\?])
```

[Extracting the symbol from string in JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/wynrmqck/):

```
var symbol = /\d([\:#!\?])/.exec('kljl2324?')[1];
```

[Removing *all* occurrences of symbol in a string](https://jsfiddle.net/nadp3zqp/):

```
var replaced = 'kljl2:324?'.replace(/\d([\:#!\?])/g, '');
```